# How to change GMSPlacePicker dialog box title (ios, swift or objective-c)

Tags: ios, gmsplacepicker

I have successfully implemented the GMSPlacePicker Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2.2. The dialog box shows but it shows in English. Doesn't care about the language of the phone. How do I change the title of the dialog form "Select a location" to "Something else"?

For people who always needs to see some code, below is my code to display the picker. Objective C answers are welcome as well:

```
// MARK: - Target Action Methods
func didTapSelectFromMap() {
    DLog("current location: \(locationManager.location)")

    guard let location = locationManager.location else {
        return
    }

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

    let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + 0.001, center.longitude + 0.001)
    let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - 0.001, center.longitude - 0.001)

    let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
    let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)

    placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

    placePicker.pickPlaceWithCallback({ (place: GMSPlace?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

            let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) in })

            ac.addAction(ok)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                self.presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })

            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        self.processPlace(place)
    })
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same problem and did not found anything yet.

Comment: The version I am using now does seem to fix the problem. - GooglePlacePicker (2.1.1), - GoogleMaps (2.1.1), - GooglePlaces (2.1.1). On my English phone I see it in English, on the Turkish phone I see it in Turkish.